# Prevent Word Breaks for link - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some links that I would like to prevent from being broken up when a `wrap` is needed. I would rather the whole entire link be moved to another line rather than half of the link.

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XD8zG/)

Is there any way to make a class only break 'full' if a `word-break` is needed? (meaning that if the content of that class will exceed the lines, instead of breaking it, just create a new line with it).

I hope this makes sense; thank you for your time.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    Here is some text within this grey box; <a href="#">And here is the link</a>.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 290px;
}
.box a {
    background: aqua;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6azW/)

```
.box a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: aqua;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```