# Don't break words in title class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css

**I have a Wordpress website...**

I am dynamically populating titles of posts within a carousel on a page.

The post populate like below. *(I have a class wrapped around the post titles for added selector).*

```
<span class="p_title"> 5 Technologies that will Revolutionize Mobile </span>
```

The problem occurs when post titles are as large as above -- which occurs in enough instances to care.. eg below..

**5 Technologies that will Revolutionize M

obile**

I would like to set the wrap to not break right in between the WORD but after it.

**5 Technologies that will Revolutionize 

Mobile**

Currently my css for `.p_title` is:

```
.p_title {
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior? you sure you don't have some other css that's affecting this?

Comment: CSS: white-space: nowrap; AND OR word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Word Breaks for link - CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451115/prevent-word-breaks-for-link-css)

Comment: Is is the default behavior... if something is interfering, just override it with `white-space:normal;` and/or `word-wrap:normal;`.

Comment: There has to be more going on.  That CSS does exactly what you're asking of us.  I'd say to use `white-space`, but that will prevent the entire line from breaking.  You need to give us more to work with.

Comment: some part of your carousel style might be breaking it down. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try defaulting both the white-space and word-break back to normal:

```
.p_title {
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    word-break: normal;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Something else is breaking it up.  If it's script related, this may not do anything to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Long words shouldn't break inside a word unless the CSS `word-wrap` property has been set to `word-wrap: break-word;`. If it has, you should be able to revert to the default behavior of only breaking *between* words by setting the property to `word-wrap: normal;`.